# Jenkins does not recognize setting env variables using set -a

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, groovy

I have a bash file that is used to set env variables. It is called `setter.sh` and contains something like this

```
set -x
var1="something"
```

in my jenkinsfile I do this

```
sh ". setter.sh"
sh "echo $var1"
```

However `$var1` is not recognized. What could be the reasoning of this?

Comment: You can't have spaces around `=` in the assignment.

Comment: I have edited the question. My original script has no space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not the spaces, it's the step syntax. You have two separate steps (commands) in two separate shells. `sh ". setter.sh"` runs in one shell and quits. The second command, `sh "echo $var1"` runs in a separate shell that does not know about the first's environment.

Either use a [multi-line shell](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/) command or [Environment Injector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) plugin or some other means. ([warning](https://serverfault.com/a/959296/189417)).

Also, `set -x` is not relevant to the question, but [set option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) in subject is `set -a` (export), body is `set -x` (trace).